# Not able to run lambdasoup example

Tags: web-scraping, ocaml

I can't seem to run run one snippet of code given as example in [lambdasoup](http://aantron.github.io/lambdasoup/).  Whenever I run the code it gives `error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type string list` pointing to the `""` argument of `String.concat`. But `trimmed_texts li` will give it the `string list` it expects, so why is it complaining?

example html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="odd">
    <li>1. One</li>
    <li>3. Three</li>
    <li>5. Five</li>
    <li>7. Seven </li>
    <li>9. Nine</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="even">
    <li>2. Two</li>
    <li>4. Four</li>
    <li>6. Six</li>
    <li>8. Eight</li>
    <li>10. Ten</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

ocaml snippet:

```
(* Find the first unordered list. *)
let ul = soup $ "ul" in

(* Print the contents of all its items. *)
ul $$ "li"
|> iter (fun li ->
  trimmed_texts li |> String.concat "" |> print_endline)
```

**Note**: I'm using the library Core.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem as I was writing the question. The code works if we are explicit with the `String.concat` labeled argument `sep`:

```
(* Find the first unordered list. *)
let ul = soup $ "ul" in

(* Print the contents of all its items. *)
ul $$ "li"
|> iter (fun li ->
  trimmed_texts li |> String.concat ~sep: "" |> print_endline)
```

Comment: You should also mention that you're using Base, Core or some other standard library replacement. `Stdlib.String.concat` does not have a labeled argument

Comment: @glennsl you're right, I'm using Core, I edited the question.